# (log) File watching with citrus-framework

Tags: citrus-framework

Is there a way and/or what are best practices to watch log files from the System Under Test? 
My requirement is to validate presence/absence of log entries according known patterns produced by the SUT.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't think there is a Citrus tool specifically designed for that. But I think that is a really good idea. You could [open an issue](https://github.com/christophd/citrus) and ask for this feature.

Meanwhile, here is a solution that we have used in one of our projects to check if the *applicaiton log* contained specific strings that were generated by our test.

```
sleep(2000),
echo("Searching the log..."),
new AbstractTestAction() {
    @Override
    public void doExecute(TestContext context) {
        try {
            String logfile = FileUtils.getFileContentAsString(Paths.get("target", "my-super-service.log").toAbsolutePath().normalize());
            if (!logfile.contains("ExpectedException: ... | Details: BOOM!.")) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Missing exceptions in log");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unable to get log");
        }
    }
}
```

**OR** you can replace that simple contains with a more elegant solution:

```
String grepResult = grepForLine(LOGFILE_PATH, ".*: SupermanMissingException.*");
if (grepResult == null) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Expected error log entry not found");
}
```

The function goes over each line searching for a match to the regex supplied.

```
public String grepForLine(Path path, String regex) {
        Pattern regexp = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = regexp.matcher("");

        String msg = null;

        try (
                BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(path, Charset.defaultCharset());
                LineNumberReader lineReader = new LineNumberReader(reader)
        ) {
            String line;
            while ((line = lineReader.readLine()) != null) {
                matcher.reset(line); //reset the input
                if (matcher.find()) {
                    msg = "Line " + lineReader.getLineNumber() + " contains the error log: " + line;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return msg;
}
```

Comment: Hi Lila, Thanks for your answer and solution (pretty straight forward). At the time I am evaluating Citrus to use it in an ESB integration Projekt the Framework looks very promising and probably support that what wee need. And for sure I will ask for such a feature if wee decide using Citrus  :-)